# Can't get the_content of the parent page from its single post?

Tags: posts, pages, single

This is a page that list posts witht he category `Content (CDs)`:

```
<div id="tagline">
    <div class="container">
        <?php // Run main loop (The Loop). ?>
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="content0">
            <?php the_content(); // <- I want to get this ?>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- .container -->
</div><!-- #content-bottom -->
<div id="content">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mainbar">
            <?php $custom_posts = new WP_Query(); ?>
            <?php $custom_posts->query('category_name=Content (CDs)'); ?>
            <?php while ($custom_posts->have_posts()) : $custom_posts->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content-block-4">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_post_thumbnail('large'); ?></a>
                    <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

`single.php` has the following:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="content0">
        <?php $parent = get_post($post->post_parent); ?>
        <?php $parent->post_content; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

But still can't get `the_content` of the parent page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It could do with the fact that `posts` have no parent where as `pages` do?

Comment: @Bainternet I've tested posts parents, for instance with the bbPress 'Forum' custom post type. Effectively the 'Reply' custom post type act as their children (I'm not very sure).

Comment: ok, thats a custom post type, not posts.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an echo infront of `$parent->post_content;`(assuming you want to output it), did you just forget to put that in what you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do two things

1. add '*echo*' to last line

<?php echo $parent->post_content; ?>

1. add '*global $post;*', before accessing the $post.

let me know if this does not work.

Comment: +1 - Should of scrolled down the screen before posting my comment.

Comment: Though i personally don't think the global is necessary, it will likely work as is, `$post` usually has scope inside template files.